# Неадекватно переписывает эллементы

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, функции, динамические-массивы

Дан динамичный двухмерный массив. Удалить все строчки и столбцы на пересечении которых есть "0"
Нормально удаляет только строчки. Столбцы не нормально(удаляет только с конца, даже если в первом есть "0").
Помогите

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int** Memory(int col, int row) {
    int **arr = new int*[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[col];
    }
    return arr;
}
void Rand(int col, int row, int **arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 20;
        }
    }
}
void RowColDel(int **arr, int row, int col);
void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int col = 5;
    int row = 5;
    int **arr = Memory(col, row);
    Rand(col, row, arr);
    Print(col, row, arr);
    cout << endl;
    RowColDel(arr, row, col);
    //Delete(arr, col, row);
}

void RowColDel(int **arr, int row, int col) {   
    int row1 = row, col1 = col;

    int **tmp = Memory(col1, row1);
    for (int i = 0, i1 = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        bool rows = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                rows = true;
                break;
            }
            else
                rows = false;
        }
        if (rows == false) {
            tmp[i1] = arr[i];
            i1++;
        }
        else
            row1--;
    }

    for (int i = 0, i1 = 0; i < col; i++)
    {
        bool cols = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                cols = true;
                break;
            }
            else
                cols = false;
        }
        if (cols == false) {
            tmp[i1] = arr[i];
            i1++;
        }
        else
            col1--;
    }
    Print(col1, row1, tmp);
 //   Delete(tmp, col1, row1);
}
```

Comment: функцию Delete(tmp, col1, row1); приведите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;



int main(void){
    const int ROWS = 5;
    const int COLS = 4;

    int mat[ROWS][COLS] = {
        { 1, 1, 0, 4 },
        { 2, 0, 3, 4 },
        { 3, 3, 3, 4 },
        { 4, 4, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 5, 3, 0 }
    };

    int i, j;
    int rows = ROWS;
    int cols = COLS;

    //вывод исходной матрицы
    for(i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            cout << mat[i][j] << ' ';
        cout.put('\n');
    }
    cout.put('\n');


    //удаление
    for(i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
            if(mat[i][j] != 0)
                continue;

            for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
                memcpy(&mat[r][j], &mat[r][j + 1],(cols-(j+1))*sizeof(int));

            //смещение строк
            for(int c = 0; c < cols; ++c){
                for(int r = i; r < (rows - 1); ++r)
                    mat[r][c] = mat[r + 1][c];
            }
            --cols;
            --rows;
            --i;
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    //вывод обработаной матрицы
    for(i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            cout << mat[i][j] << ' ';
        cout.put('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

вывод

```
1 1 0 4 
2 0 3 4 
3 3 3 4 
4 4 3 4 
5 5 3 0 

3 
4
```

http://ideone.com/fdYtY1 вот тут весь код с выводом